I want to figure out how to count the number of months consecutively in a query
I am trying to extract data in relation to customer savings on Teradata. So I want to figure out how many months in a row a customer has saved money in 2024 and to display that as a number. I.e if a customer saved from Jan to June = 6 months.
I also want to ensure that it returns the higher number as well. I.e if a customer saves 4 months in a row but missed 1 month and then saves for 6 months, I want to return 6.
I have already got the data that tells us if a customer saved for that month,I just need to do this final step of counting, and showing the highest number.
Am I approaching this the right way? Please help as its for a project, happy to provide more details if needed.
The customer base table just has the customer details i.e customer_ID, name, email etc.
The query looks  something like this:
SELECT
CUSTOMER_ID,
MAX(JAN24) AS JAN24_T,
MAX(FEB24) as FEB24_T,
MAX(MAR24) AS MAR24_T,
MAX(APR24) AS APR24_T,
MAX(MAY24) AS MAY24_T,
MAX(JUN24) AS JUN24_T,
MAX(JUL24) AS JUL24_T,
MAX(AUG24) AS AUG24_T,
MAX(SEP24) AS SEP24_T,
MAX(OCT24) AS OCT24_T,
MAX(NOV24) as NOV24_T,
MAX(DEC24) as DEC24_T,
MONTH_DATE,
ROW NUMBER() OVER(PARTITIION BY CUSTOMER_ID, ORDER BY MONTH_DATE) as CONSEC_MONTHS

FROM CUSTOMER_BASE BASE

LEFT JOIN SAVING_GROWTH SAV
ON BASE.CUSTOMER_ID = SAV.CUSTOMER_ID

QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CUSTOMER_ID ORDER BY CONSEC_MONTHS DESC) = 1

I have attached a dummy sample of what SAVING_GROWTH looks like.
For SAVING_GROWTH, when its 1, the customer saved that month. I did not write this code, but it was given to me to leverage to get the max of consecutive months saved, I hope this is enough info to resolve my question, Thanks!

Teradata supports a RESET WHEN clause for window functions. Perhaps that could be used in conjunction with LAG to test whether the months /  savings are consecutive. You likely would want to do that in an inner query before you pivot the rows.

How would that look with the query above? Does the Months_T (i.e JAN24_T, FEB24_T etc) need to be in 1 column as opposed to 12 different columns for this to work? I'm a bit confused on how to structure my query for this, Thanks!

Yes, window functions work with values in the same columns, different rows - not across columns in the same row. I was (perhaps incorrectly) assuming you calculate the month totals from some more detailed information. Maybe edit the question to show the structure of the source tables.

I have added some additional info + a screenshot of the SAVING_GROWTH table structure, hope that helps

That structure isn't useful for what you are trying to do. With one row per customer per month, you can use "gaps and islands" type logic or potentially RESET WHEN to compute the length of consecutive groups. For this very specific case you could potentially UNPIVOT the SAVING_GROWTH table in a subquery / CTE.

Agreed with the structure! So I've applied the UNPIVOT on the SAVING_GROWTH which fixes that issue, however, is there a way I can put the months in order per customerID? Once its in order, I can apply RESET WHEN for the consecutive months of saving in a row
